# How to find eigenvectors of matrix with complex eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix

\begin{pmatrix} 
-3 & 1 \\
-2 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}

and I found the eigenvalues, which are $\lambda_{1} = -2+i \ $ and $\ \lambda_{2}= -2-i$,

and now I have to find the eigenvectors, but they are with complex values and I don't know the steps for that.

Edit:
So for the first eigenvalue $\lambda_{1}$= -2 + i, I tried:

\begin{pmatrix} 
-3-(-2+i) & 1 \\ 
-2 & -1-(-2+i) 
\end{pmatrix}

and then I've got:

```
(-1-i)x + y = 0
 -2x + (1-i)y = 0
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How would you find the eigenvectors if the eigenvalues were real?

Comment: just do the same operations you would do for real eigenvalues, remember you can multiply, add, substract and divide complex numbers like you would do with real numbers. so the algorithm is basically the same

Comment: Next notice your two lines are compatible, line2 = line1 $\times(1-i)$. So you have two variables and one equation. Means you can choose $x=1$ for instance and get eigenvector $(1,1+i)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution of an analogous problem as a starting point for you:

Here's a matrix with eigenvalues $\pm i$:
$$
A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0}
$$
I'll find the eigenvector for $+i$. I want to find a vector $v$ with
$$
Av = i ~v,
$$
right? I convert that to
$$
Av = iI ~v\\
(A-iI)v = 0
$$
So now I want to find the kernel of
$$
\pmatrix{-i & 1 \\ -1 & -i},
$$
so I need to solve
$$
\pmatrix{-i & 1 \\ -1 & -i} \cdot \pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0}
$$
which becomes
$$
-ix + y = 0 \\
-x - iy = 0
$$
we see that the second equation is just $-i$ times the first one, so we can simply solve the first equation. Picking $x = 1$ (because it's easy!), we get $y = i$, so **one** eigenvector is
$$
\pmatrix{1\\i}.
$$
Any (complex) nonzero multiple of this is also an eigenvector, so
$$
\pmatrix{i\\-1}, 
\pmatrix{2\\2i}, 
\pmatrix{1+i\\-1+i} 
$$
are all eigenvectors as well. (If we'd chosen $x = i, x = 2, x = 1 + i$, they're what we'd have found when we solved for $y$.)

Comment: What is the need for the $(A-iI)$ transform ? You can just go for $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=i\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ and get $\begin{cases}y=ix\\-x=iy\end{cases}$ all the same.

Comment: If, this matrix were represented by some linear transformation on real space, then how could you say that eigenvectors can exist!!

Comment: Even eigenvalue doesn't exist!!!

Comment: So I tried to find the eigenvector with your solution, but then I've got lost again, can you please help me?

Comment: @Subhajit The matrix $A$ represents a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $90^°$ clockwise, and thus has no real eigenvalues, anyway we are talking about complex eigenvalues

Comment: @Peter Melech suppose, we take the linear transformation T from R² to R², defined by T(x,y)=(y,-x),then what do you say!

Comment: Definition of eigenvector rejects the possibility of complexity!

Comment: I edited my post, you can see what I've got @Subhajit

Comment: If you were looking for the solutions of those equations(which you were given), then you have to take all the possible values for x,y in the complex numbers' field which are satisfying those two equations!

Comment: @Subhajit exactly this transformation $T$ is the rotation I mentioned, and I agree it has no real eigenvalues. But the matrix $A$ can also be seen as a linear transformation on $\mathbb{C}^2$ and as such it has complex eigenvalues. The definition of an eigenvector doesn't reject the possibility of complexity at all, see e.g.[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors), if you choose the underlying field to be algebraically closed you will always have eigenvalues, and eigenvectors

Comment: Thank you, Peter, for helping Subhajit understand about complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @Martina: You can do exactly what I did: you can say "these two equations are multiples of one another, so I can simply solve the first one. To do that, I'll start somewhere simple, and choose $x = 1$, and then solve for $y$." In other words...keep following the script.